# Pivot results not working for me

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query that generates my pivot results:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    #tmp1.Name,  
    DATEDIFF(D,#tmp1.AuthDate,#tmp1.AuthExpirationDate) AS AuthLenInDays,
    #tmp1.NbrOfAuthorizations, 
    #tmp1.MODE
    FROM #tmp1
    LEFT JOIN #tmp2 
    ON #tmp2.AuthID = #tmp1.AuthID 
    GROUP BY #tmp1.Name, #tmp1.NbrOfAuthorizations, #tmp1.AuthDate, #tmp1.AuthExpirationDate,  #tmp1.MODE

) AS InnerTbl

PIVOT
(AVG(AuthLenInDays)  FOR [MODE] IN ([Preservation]) 

) PivotResults1
```

The results are as follows:

```
Name        NbrOfAuthorizations     Preservation
Centro          1                   79
Dennis          1                   92
Therapy Center  1                   68
Florez          1                   92
```

I have two problems that I have not been able to figure out, I've tried everything I can think of and even other suggestions from stackoverflow.

1. I can't figure out how to change the name of the right-most column (Preservation)
   in my results.  It's an average number so I'd like to label that
   column 'Average'.
2. Also, the NbrOfAuthorizations needs to be summed for all the values
   in the table.  I have tried using a pivot and this gets me close but
   not all the way there, I have also tried using a SUM in the InnerTbl
   query but that isn't it either.

If I take my raw data and export that to excel and do a pivot there, I can see the numbers and what I should be getting.  I am trying to take that process and do it purely in SQL.  Based on the data in the table, the values for the SUM should be

```
   Name     NbrOfAuthorizations     Preservation
    Centro          5                   79
    Dennis          1                   92
    Therapy Center  57                  68
    Florez          1                   92
```

Any masters of pivot out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't need pivot at all:

```
select
    t1.Name,  
    sum(t1.NbrOfAuthorizations) as NbrOfAuthorizations,
    avg(datediff(dd, t1.AuthDate, t1.AuthExpirationDate)) as AuthLenInDays
from #tmp1 as t1
    -- looks like you don't need join also, or there're multiple rows
    -- in #tmp2 for row in #tmp1
    -- left outer join #tmp2 as t2 on t2.AuthID = t1.AuthID 
where t1.mode = 'Preservation'
group by t1.Name
```